# I need a class that controls which view is displayed

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-gridview, extends, sudoku

I want to create the following behavior.
Lets say I have a class A and B which extends view.
Now I want to create a class (X for Example) that holds padding values(or other layout configurations such as width). Inside the remaining width/height of X I want to draw A or B. Lets say I have an external button and I press it it cycles which class is displayed A/B.
I am new to android and I do not know how to approach this.

For the moment I want to get the functionality described above. And then I can adapted to my needs.I am working on a Sudoku game. I  have a custom gridview, and every item is a customview.
This customview works ok atm. But I would like it to separate it in 2 things.
One that draws numbers, and one that draws notes (possible numbers in the cell).
So in my case I should have 81 (9x9) of X which display A or B.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If A or B extend from View, just use this to show A

```
A.visibility = View.VISIBLE
B.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

use this to show B

```
B.visibility = View.VISIBLE
A.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

Comment: I see. But how should I create my parent. Should it be a layout? which holds A and B on top of each other and I simply make 1 visible? I need this "container" so I can use it 81times in my base adapter for the custom grid view.

Comment: use FrameLayout as parent, so A and B can position at same place.